# Incompatible types in assignment in c when assigning same structure members to other members

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure, assignment-operator

I am working with `c`-file i am getting the error incompatible type in assignment.
 My Code is as follows -

```
typedef struct
{
 float a1;
 float a2; .... 

 float a26;
}CPS_Param;

typedef struct
{
int b1;
CPS_Param *Param;
}CPS_IPOP;


void main () 
{
CPS_Param pParam;
CPS_IPOP *pStr;

set_Param(&pParam,0.04,0.001,0.01,0.67,0.07,....26parameters);

.....my program

pStr->Param->a1 = pParam.a1;
...26 repeat

}

set_Param(CPS_Param *pParam,float Param1, float Param2,....26 assignments)
{
pParam->a1 = Param1;   // here i am getting compatability error
pParam->a2 = Param2;   // here i am getting compatability error
...
pParam->a26= Param26;  // here i am getting compatability error
}

`
```

My main intention is ....i want to create two members one as odinary like `pParam` and other like `*Param` which is inside `(*pStr)`. I will first installize the pParam by a function and other values passing as arguments.  Finally at the end of the program i will copy the `pParam` parameters directly to the `*Param` (inside `*pStr`). But while i am writing the program i shows incompability of assignment. All the structure members are of different parameters of same data type which cannot be combined as array. Can you point out the mistake i have done...

Comment: Provide a small example that produces the error and the exact text of the error, then you'll get meaningful help.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are listing 26 members individually instead of just using `float arr[26]`?

Comment: CPS_Param structure contains 26 variables like float a1,....,float a26. So, i want to instalize the one member of structure with my predefined values by a functions by passing values as arguments...

Comment: `void main` is non-standard. Omitting function return type is non-standard. Omitting a function prototype with `float` arguments is non-standard. Fix all this then see if the problem remains. If it does, prepare a self-contained example ready to be copied, pasted and compiled.

Comment: Parameters `a1` through `a26` and structure elements `a1` through `a26` look awfully like an array of 26 (or possibly 27) elements in disguise. The main problem with them is that they make the code unmanageable — witness your assignment statements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you have not allocated memory for the CPS_Param pointer inside the CPS_IPOP structure. So you will get a segv when the program is run.

What compiler are you using? Gcc compiles it just fine.

Comment: I am using Gcc compilers only...but still i am facing incompatability assignment issue...